# Why cannot I print the data inside a `div` container?

Tags: javascript, arrays

The code below displays the data but outside the `div` container.

What should I do to display the array data inside the `div` container?

```js
let jokes = [
  //Array (String data Collection) (cannot show due to security reason)
]
let length = jokes.length - 1;
let a = Math.floor(Math.random() * length);
let b = jokes[a];
document.getElementById("jokes-result").innerHTML = "Joke For Today is: " + b + "<br> Joke Number: " + a;
```

```html
<div id="jokes-result"></div>
```

Comment: works for me, your code has a problem tho. If your jokes array has for example 3 elements the real length of the array is 3 but if you do `let length=jokes.length-1;` that will give you only 2 which means that you will never get the last element of your array in your HTML

Comment: That `document.write(b);` makes no sense there (it writes the value there where that statement occurs, so of course that is outside of your div) - remove it.

Comment: i want to display the values of b to the html inside the div because the I need to design the output which is only possible inside the div.

Comment: We already know what you need, and it works. `That document.write(b)` tho should be removed becuz that will print the same value but outside of your div which makes no sense as CBroe mentioned

Comment: ok ,i removed that, after that too the string doesn't print inside the div container,

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this code other than _when_ it might run (and `length` should `jokes.length`). Check out [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14028959/283366)

Answer (score -2):

If you assign an id to the div container where you want to display the array, you can use document.getElementById() to display the array inside the div container.

```html
<div class="minor-section" id="jokes">
    <h2> joke here</h2>
</div>
```

then you could call "jokes" in getElementById() instead of "jokes-result"

```js
const jokes = document.getElementById('jokes')
```